# Creating an excel file from a DataGridView is returning an error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data from a DataGridView but i am receiving the error: "Excel can not open the file because the file format or extension is not valid"

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ExcelOutput_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcelOutput.Click
    Dim fileName = "ExcelOutput.xlsx"
    Dim filePath As String = "H:\" + fileName
    If Not File.Exists(filePath) Then
        File.Create(filePath).Close()
    End If

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim line As String = ""
    Dim d As String = ","
    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        line = line + c.Name & d
    Next
    sb.AppendLine(line)
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        line = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            line = Convert.ToString(line & (i).ToString()) & d
        Next
        sb.AppendLine(line)
    Next

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString())

End Sub
```

The file is being created, with the file name "ExcelOutput.xlsx" but i get that error when i try to open it. Not sure why

Comment: You appear to be trying to create a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file, but you're are giving it an extension of ".xlsx" which is an XML Excel file. Give the file an extension of ".csv".

Comment: I am not very smart. Thank you Blackwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumping that data into a file and giving it a .xlsx file extension doesn't actually make it a valid excel file.

Change the file extension to .CSV and it will open properly.

If you want to work with excel files, I would recommend looking up the Office.Excel.Interop library.  Here is a good place to start:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel